# Soundcloud HTML5 Player Not Showing Up in IE9

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, soundcloud

I've put a Soundcloud HTML5 player on my website and am generally quite pleased with it.

However, while browser testing in IE9 on Windows 7, The player is not loading, and I am seeing the following error in the debugging console:

```
SCRIPT429: Automation server can't create object 
widget-b8220e90.js, line 2 character 1738
```

The poking around that I have been able to do suggests that this has something to do with the IE9 security settings and/or ActiveX, which makes me shudder. I have IE9 running on its default security settings.

Is there anything that can be done to get the HTML5 player to show in this situation, or will I need to fallback to the flash player?

EDIT: The problem also occurs in IE8, which isn't surprising but I add for completeness' sake

EDIT: I am seeing the problem using the Win7/IE9 Virtual Machine provided by Microsoft at their new [Modern IE](http://www.modern.ie/) site, and using the default security settings in IE9

Comment: Better ask Soundcloud support for this

Comment: @DaveStern, I'll discuss with the devs in charge - don't worry though: there's no ActiveX in the widget! Is this always reproducible on every widget, or just sometimes, or just on certain tracks/sets?

Comment: @nickf I am not sure, We only use the widget once on our site. The embed code we use is the following: `<iframe width="98%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fusers%2F897711&amp;color=c9a77d&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=true"></iframe>` I believe that's standard copy/pasted, except we tweaked the width from 100% to 98% for our design

Comment: @nickf, I am having the same exact problem only I'm having it in IE 10.  I get the same error.  I'm also using default settings.  I am not on a VM.  In fact, I cannot even visit SoundCloud.com in IE 10.  When I do, I receive an error.

Answer (score 2):

I used the same code you specified above to try to reproduce, but it works fine for me in IE9. In compatibility mode it just falls back to the old Flash widget. Can you have a look here and say if it still doesn’t work for you?

http://jsbin.com/otulas

Comment: Hrmm, I just tried your helpful JSBin and got the same error. I am using the new IE9 VM provided my Microsoft at their [Modern IE](http://www.modern.ie/) site. I am then using IE9 on its default security settings, under the assumption that's how most Windows users roll (click the green thing that says 'recommended', go on with life)

Comment: VMs aren’t always very reliable. I’m often getting variable results. I have checked with a real Windows 7 machine + IE9 and with a VM. These are the [security settings](http://scr.timbormans.com/1owx5d7f3n28.png) that I use. Are they similar to yours?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a problem in IE, testing on IE8 and this is what I have found:

1. The Widget API Playground doesn't work.
2. URLs with "/favorites" doesn't work, as in the Widget API Playground.
3. Getting this error:

> "Webpage error details
>   Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
>   
> Line: 1
>   
> Char: 6061
>   
> Code: 0
>   
> URI: https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js
>   
>   So I did unminify the JS file and got that it's talking about this line of code:
>   
> `return r && r.instance ? r.instance : (i = a.indexOf(S(e)) > -1, s = new p(e), f.push(new d(s, e, i)), s)`

It is important to mention that the player works fine without any API and without including the API script.

Hope this can be helpful for the dev team.

Comment: I personally ended up detecting the browser and if it's IE<10 then I'm using the Flash API instead of the HTML5 API.
Flash API documentation: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget

Answer (score 0):

IE9 and 10 don't like third party cookies. SoundCloud's HTML5 widget uses those.

More from SoundCloud: http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/1331463-why-is-my-widget-not-showing-up-in-internet-explorer-

More from Microsoft: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_8/soundcloud-html5-widget-wont-display-in-ie-9-or-10/79aaab55-44d8-414f-9d06-939bbdf25676